# survival::tmerge() giving as.Date.numeric(value) error

Tags: r, survival

I'm trying to tmerge some data together to do some survival analysis, but I keep getting an error.

```
library(survival)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- data.frame(id = "62103",
                  hire.date = ymd("2016-05-16"),
                  end.date = ymd(Sys.Date())
)
job <- data.frame(id = c("62103", "62103"),
                  job1 = c("level 1 coder", "level 2 coder"),
                  start.date = c(ymd("2016-05-16"), ymd("2017-05-16")),
                  end.date = c(ymd("2017-05-16"), NA)
)

df2 <- tmerge(df1, df1, id = id,
              tstart = hire.date,
              tstop = end.date)
df3 <- tmerge(df2, job, id = id,
              job = tdc(start.date, job1)
)
```

This throws the error:

> Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

Here is some information about my session:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.7.4   survival_2.44-1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.1  magrittr_1.5    Matrix_1.2-17   tools_3.6.1    
 [5] Rcpp_1.0.2      stringi_1.4.3   splines_3.6.1   grid_3.6.1     
 [9] knitr_1.24      stringr_1.4.0   xfun_0.9        lattice_0.20-38
```

Comment: From which package you used `tdc`

Comment: `survival::tdc`

Comment: I get `survival::tdc
Error: 'tdc' is not an exported object from 'namespace:survival'`  I have the ssame version `survival_2.44-1.1`

Comment: Let's clarify! With `tdc(start.date, job)` are you saying that time-dependent covariate is date type? I was expecting it to be a numeric type...

Comment: Hey @VitaliAvagyan: The time-dependent covariate should be a string type -- what job did you have before you terminated?

Comment: Hey @akrun, `tdc` is defined here on page 145. I'm afraid I don't know much more than that.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue with `tdc` is that some date math does not preform correctly. Converting (back and forth?) to numeric solves this.

```
library(survival)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(id = "62103",
                  hire.date = ymd("2016-05-16"),
                  end.date = ymd(Sys.Date())
) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.Date, as.numeric)
job <- data.frame(id = c("62103", "62103"),
                  job1 = c("level 1 stacker", "level 2 stacker"),
                  start.date = c(ymd("2016-05-16"), ymd("2017-05-16")),
                  end.date = c(ymd("2017-05-16"), NA)
)%>% 
  mutate_if(is.Date, as.numeric)

df2 <- tmerge(df1, df1, id = id,
              tstart = hire.date,
              tstop = end.date)
df3 <- tmerge(df2, job, id = id,
              job = event(start.date, job1)
) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, as.Date, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tdc` function is internal to the `tmerge` function. Here's its definition from the top of the code:

```
 assign("tdc", function(time, value = NULL) {
        x <- list(time = time, value = value)
        class(x) <- "tdc"
        x
    }, envir = new)
```

It expects the name of a time argument and the name of a time-varying variable and is supposed to create a new variable from an old variable. It will inherit the search path of the call to `tmerge`. What was given as the second argument was an entire dataframe (and was assigned back to the name of that dataframe as well), so it's not surprising that an error was thrown, although I will grant that the error message was not particularly informative. I suppose it's possible that simply changing the column name so it's not conflated wtih the dataframe name would suffice. Let's check: Nope, changing the job column name to 'job1' in the `job` dataframe and the call to the second `tmerge` operation still fails.

The example in the `tmerge` help page performs as advertised:

```
temp <- subset(pbc, id <= 312, select=c(id:sex, stage)) # baseline data
pbc2 <- tmerge(temp, temp, id=id, endpt = event(time, status))
pbc2 <- tmerge(pbc2, pbcseq, id=id, ascites = tdc(day, ascites),
               bili = tdc(day, bili), albumin = tdc(day, albumin),
               protime = tdc(day, protime), alk.phos = tdc(day, alk.phos))

fit <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, endpt==2) ~ protime + log(bili), data=pbc2)
```

I also suspect a larger example is needed for successful operation of `tmerge` in a addition to using column names as arguments to `tdc`. The `df2` example only has one line of data, so how it's supposed to be time-varying is unclear. I also noticed that there appeared to be no status variable in the example whereas that was the first operation in Therneau's example: `pbc2 <- tmerge(temp, temp, id=id, endpt = event(time, status))`

The help page strongly suggest that users review the included vignette on time-varying covariates.

Comment: This is helpful!

Although, I thought that `start.date` was time varying (it changes by a year) and `job1` also varied. (I'm changing the name in the example, thank you).

Furthermore, the example in the vignette clearly works with just one individual and two observations of the time dependent covariate. The below works just fine for me.

`temp <- subset(pbc, id <= 1, select=c(id:sex, stage)) # baseline data`

`pbc2 <- tmerge(temp, temp, id=id, endpt = event(time, status))`

`pbc2 <- tmerge(pbc2, pbcseq[pbcseq$id == 1,], id=id, ascites = tdc(day, ascites)
               )`